# Type of drill that can make quick work of pre-drilling red-heads / concrete screws

Tags: concrete, screws, drill

I have a 17 pound hammer drill with a rotary attachment rated at 7.5Joules. That's plenty of *impact* energy but it is actually a bit soft on the rotary torque. It basically is meant to *demolish* concrete not *drill* through it.

The hammer drill managed to get by for a few dozen redheads/concrete screws: but it had already had a long previous life demo'ing concrete and is ready to be retired. It did the job for the screws but slowly and only with a *lot* of hand-holding and encouragement. What is a better option for its successor?

What I am wondering: will a more traditional drill (but a beefy one) - which is focused solely on the *rotational* torque aspect - be a better match to the pure drilling need here?  If so what kind of drill would be best here?  When I think of those drills (e.g. an old school *Chicago*) it is more of wood and metal that come to mind. Are those drills also good candidates for concrete?

We primarily use three and five inch concrete screws of 1/2" diameter to fasten mud sills, beams and/or studs into a concrete slab floor.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: @EdBeal I was asking about genres of tools and provided the above as examples. I'm sorry that were not sufficiently clear.  It is a valid question:  are hammer drills appropriate , the more traditional rotary drills, or is there another genre altogether that I am not aware of.

Comment: Since your goal is to drill holes, I think what you want is a [hammer drill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_drill), not a [rotary hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_hammer). However, it sounds like you could use a lighter duty one since you're drilling reasonably small holes. If you were looking at 4" holes through a poured concrete foundation wall, then the big boy you have would be appropriate.

Comment: West coast. I do not down vote or vote to close without there being an explanation since there was none and I was the 3rd VTC I left one…

Comment: The comment from @FreeMan would be an appropriate answer to this question

Comment: @jsotola I removed paragraphs 4 and 5 but 1 and 2 are pertinent.

Comment: When fastening to concrete I drill with a Bosch rotary hammer and then drive the screws with a battery powered impact driver.

Comment: @P2000 Feel free to make that an answer.  I might ask : how long does the rotary hammer take ?  Mine was taking 60+ seconds per screw even with heavy elbow grease.

Comment: There is no such thing as drilling concrete or stone.  The material doesn't drill. What so-called "concrete drills" do is spall/crush/demolish concrete in a cylinderical pattern.

Comment: OK - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Could the OP be specific about what size/length of fasteners are being used? I have a battery powered (yellow) that hits harder than my Makita "bulldog"...

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  I updated the question:  we use 3 and 5 inch screws driving mud sills beams and/or studs into concrete slab.

Comment: Good start, but what diameter drill bit?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  1/2"

Comment: Given that, a Bosch Bulldog style of tool (marketing/ratings vary, but aim for 1-1/8" or ~3.0 joules) will suit pretty perfectly. Discard bits after they slow down appreciably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When fastening to concrete I drill with a Bosch rotary hammer and then drive the screws with a battery powered impact driver.

For a 5/32 drill it takes me perhaps 10 to 20s to drill 2..3in deep.

It then takes another 10s to drive the screw through 1.5in lumber and into the concrete.

(Numbers are very rough based on memory)